# Média de 2 valores seguidos de uma lista

Tags: javascript, python

Estou com uma dúvida:
estou tentando resolver um exercício para aprendizado, que é o seguinte:

informe uma lista. Ex: `[1, 3, 5, 1, -10]`, e retorne a média entre o número e o número seguinte. Neste exemplo, deveria retornar: `[2, 4, 3, -4.5]`.
Não tenho ideia de como "fatiar" uma lista, pois ela não tem limite, poderia criar uma lista com 100 valores...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando uma lista de tamanho indefinido é só iterar com um `while` fazendo o cálculo da média da posição atual + a posição seguinte. O laço encerra quando ele alcançar a posição de `tamanho da sua lista -1`.

Por exemplo:

```
lista = [1, 3, 5, 1, -10]

tamanho = len(lista)
pos = 0
while pos < tamanho-1:
    print((lista[pos]+lista[pos+1])/2)
    pos+=1
```

saída:

> 2.0
>
> 4.0
>
> 3.0
>
> -4.5

Ou, como você disse nos comentários, pode ser feito o controle através da exclusão do primeiro item da lista. Nesse caso o `while` vai encerrar quando a lista tiver menos do que 2 itens.

```
lista = [1, 3, 5, 1, -10]

pos = 0
while len(lista) >= 2:
    print((lista[pos]+lista[pos+1])/2)
    lista.pop(0)
```

Comment: Pow, show! Eu estava tentando fazer um pouco diferente, pois como sou iniciante, não entendo muito bem, então eu estava tentando pegar sempre o indice[0] e o indice[1], fazer a media dos 2, e então remover o indice[0], passando seu lugar para o próximo número, será que funcionaria?

Comment: E outra, porque você usou pos < tamanho-1? Esse -1 está fazendo exatamente o que?

Comment: Funciona sim, adicionei uma segunda versão com esse approach.

Comment: O `pos < tamanho - 1` é o controle da sua lista. Como você precisa de 2 elementos para ter a média o pos vai incrementando a cada laço: começa com 0, depois 1,  2.... O laço `while` deixa de ser executado quando pos for maior do que o tamanho total da lista -1, ou seja, se a lista tiver 10 itens ele vai executar até pos = 9, para que não chegue no laço 10 e não tenha com quem fazer a média e acabe gerando um erro (a posição 11 da lista não existe).

Comment: Ah, entendi, Max! Cara, muito obrigado por esclarecer minhas dúvidas! Estou entrando nesse mundo da programação, ano que vem começo a faculdade, e quero chegar preparado já, você me ajudou a entender uma coisa muito show. Obrigado!

Comment: Show cara, não desiste e estuda pra valer. E o melhor jeito de aprender é ensinando. Então se eu te ajudei e você ficou grato ajude alguém quando tiver oportunidade. É para isso que a comunidade existe =) Ahhh, e se puder dar um voto positivo na minha resposta também ficaria feliz. Abraços

Comment: Vou ajudar sim. Estou tentando achar onde dar um voto positivo na sua resposta hahaha

Comment: Ali em cima de onde você marcou como resposta aprovada tem uma flechinha para cima e outra para baixo. Clique na flechinha para cima sempre que alguma resposta for útil e te ajudar a solucionar um problema.

Comment: Beleza, feito Max!

Comment: Seria legal você fazer o tour do site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour E uma dica final: Estude com o curso do Guanabara no Youtube, você vai evoluir bastante, é do básico ao intermediário

Comment: Não tenho 15 de reputação, pelo jeito ainda não contou meu voto positivo na sua pergunta, mas assim que chegar a 15, volto aqui e deixo o voto! Certo vou fazer esse tour, e assistir o curso do Guanabara, obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Show. Abração e bons estudos https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHz_AreHm4dlKP6QQCekuIPky1CiwmdI6